# To fetch the rehire period using lag n lead function

Tags: sql, oracle

Wanted to check whether the employee got rehired to a contract or not. If he is rehired then return the rehire period .
**If the multiple employees got rehired then return all their rehire period .**

```
Sample data:(Table 'Contract')
Employee_id        Period         Contract 
111                  202204         1NA
111                  202205          1NA
111                  202206           1NA
112                  202207           1NA
112                  202208           1NA
111                  202209           1NA
```

In the above case the output should be ,

```
Employee_id       Period           Contract
111               202209            1NA
```

The query should first check whether the employee got rehired or not, if so then return the rehire period.
If that contract has got no rehire's then return NULL.

Any other logic other than lag n lead will also be Appreciated!

Thanks in advance:)

[Image of the sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58iRq.png)

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Did you get any errors ? Also please don't post images but properly formatted ddl and dml scripts please.

Comment: SELECT t1.ARCHIVE_PERIOD, t1.PROJECT_OWNER, t1.CONTRACT_NUMBER
FROM (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
    ORDER BY ARCHIVE_PERIOD
  ) ID,
  ARCHIVE_PERIOD,
  PROJECT_OWNER,
  CONTRACT_NUMBER
  FROM ARC_WORK_CONTRACT_GENERAL WHERE CONTRACT_NUMBER='1N850248'  --AND project_owner = '1110940')  t0
INNER JOIN (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
    ORDER BY ARCHIVE_PERIOD
  ) ID,
  ARCHIVE_PERIOD,
  PROJECT_OWNER,
  CONTRACT_NUMBER
  FROM ARC_WORK_CONTRACT_GENERAL WHERE CONTRACT_NUMBER='1N850248'  --AND project_owner ='1110940')  t1
ON t1.id = t0.id + 1 AND t0.PROJECT_OWNER != t1.PROJECT_OWNER

Comment: I tried to compare the consecutive rows, but this query is not checking whether the employee got rehired or not

Comment: How exactly do you determine rehires? What must be true for a row to be identified as a rehire row? And what is the table's unique key? The period? The period + employee_id? The period + contract? The period + employee_id + contract?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner rehire is determined when the employee got hired back on to the contract after sometime
In the above data employee 111 got rehired in 202209 after the employee 112.

Comment: This is not a precise definition. If the rows for employee 112 did not exist, would that still be rehired or just, say, vacation? Can that even happen? Can there be period gaps? Can two employees work on the same contract at the same time? Again: What is the table's unique key? And again: Please describe precisely when a row is considered a rehire row. Something along the lines of: "A row is considered a rehire row when there exists another row for the same contract and ...". Learn to be precise when you want to write correct queries.

Answer (score 0):

Use `LAG` to identify if the previous period interval, then only select the ones where the interval > 1

```
create table  contracts (employee_id,period,contract) as 
(
  SELECT 111, 202204,'1NA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 111, 202205,'1NA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 111, 202206,'1NA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 111, 202209,'1NA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 112, 202207,'1NA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 112, 202208,'1NA' FROM DUAL 
);

Table CONTRACTS created.

with contracts_w_lags (
   employee_id
   ,period
   ,last_period
   ,contract
) as ( select employee_id
             ,period
             ,lag(period)
               over(partition by employee_id
                    order by period)
             ,contract
  from contracts
)
select employee_id
      ,period 
      ,contract
  from contracts_w_lags
 where period - nvl( last_period ,period ) > 1;


EMPLOYEE_ID     PERIOD CON
----------- ---------- ---
        111     202209 1NA
```

Note that your sample data only has periods within the same year. This example will fail if periods cross years.

To overcome that, create a pseudo "periods" table with a rownumber to identify consecutive rows:

```
create table  contracts (employee_id,period,contract) as 
(
  SELECT 111, 202111,'1NA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 111, 202112,'1NA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 111, 202201,'1NA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 111, 202203,'1NA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 112, 202207,'1NA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 112, 202208,'1NA' FROM DUAL 
);


Table CONTRACTS created.


with month_count ( cnt ) as 
( select months_between(
   to_date( max(period) ,'YYYYMM' )
  ,to_date( min(period) ,'YYYYMM' ))
  from contracts
),contract_start ( dt ) as 
( select to_date( min(period) ,'YYYYMM' )
  from contracts
),contract_periods ( period ,rn ) as 
( select to_char( add_months( c.dt ,level - 1 ) ,'YYYYMM' )
        ,row_number() over( order by add_months( c.dt ,level - 1 ) ) 
    from contract_start c
        ,month_count m 
    connect by level <= m.cnt + 1 
),contracts_w_lags ( employee_id ,period ,contract ,period_rn ,last_period_rn ) as 
( select c.employee_id
        ,c.period
        ,c.contract
        ,p.rn
        ,lag(p.rn) over(partition by c.employee_id order by p.rn )
  from contracts c
       join contract_periods p on c.period = p.period
)
select employee_id
      ,period
      ,contract
  from contracts_w_lags
 where period_rn - nvl( last_period_rn ,period_rn ) > 1;



EMPLOYEE_ID     PERIOD CON
----------- ---------- ---
        111     202209 1NA
```

Comment: How to modify the above query if the rehire happens not within the same year ?

Comment: Check the 2nd query. Note... please provide decent sample data (covering all cases) and in proper format (create table, insert statements). Update your question if you have additional data, don't put that in the comments

Answer (score 0):

**The answer** (after comments) **is at the end**....

It is unclear what is your expected result with this sample data:

```sql
WITH
    contracts (EMP_ID, PERIOD, CONTRACT) as 
        (
            SELECT 111, 202204, '1NA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT 111, 202205, '1NA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT 111, 202206, '1NA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT 112, 202207, '1NA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT 112, 202208, '1NA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT 111, 202209, '1NA' FROM DUAL 
        )
```

There are some multiple consecutive periods for both sample eployees. One of the options is to show first and last periods for emps with multiple periods:

```sql
SELECT  EMP_ID, Min(PREV_PERIOD) "FIRST_PERIOD", Max(PERIOD) "LAST_PERIOD", CONTRACT
FROM    (Select EMP_ID, PERIOD, CONTRACT, 
              LAG(PERIOD, 1, 0) OVER(Partition By EMP_ID Order By PERIOD) "PREV_PERIOD"
       From contracts)
WHERE   PREV_PERIOD != 0
GROUP BY  EMP_ID, CONTRACT
--  
--  R e s u l t :
--      EMP_ID FIRST_PERIOD LAST_PERIOD CONTRACT
--  ---------- ------------ ----------- --------
--         111       202204      202209 1NA      
--         112       202207      202208 1NA
```

... another could be to show them all :

```sql
SELECT  EMP_ID, PERIOD "PERIOD", PREV_PERIOD "PREV_PERIOD", CONTRACT
FROM    (Select EMP_ID, PERIOD, CONTRACT, 
              LAG(PERIOD, 1, 0) OVER(Partition By EMP_ID Order By PERIOD) "PREV_PERIOD"
       From contracts)
WHERE   PREV_PERIOD != 0
--  
--  R e s u l t :
--      EMP_ID     PERIOD PREV_PERIOD CONTRACT
--  ---------- ---------- ----------- --------
--         111     202205      202204 1NA      
--         111     202206      202205 1NA      
--         111     202209      202206 1NA      
--         112     202208      202207 1NA
```

... and if you want the same with LEAD() function

```sql
SELECT  EMP_ID, PERIOD "PERIOD", NEXT_PERIOD "NEXT_PERIOD", CONTRACT
FROM    (Select EMP_ID, PERIOD, CONTRACT, 
              LEAD(PERIOD, 1, 0) OVER(Partition By EMP_ID Order By PERIOD) "NEXT_PERIOD"
       From contracts)
WHERE   NEXT_PERIOD != 0
--  
--  R e s u l t :
--      EMP_ID     PERIOD NEXT_PERIOD CONTRACT
--  ---------- ---------- ----------- --------
--         111     202204      202205 1NA      
--         111     202205      202206 1NA      
--         111     202206      202309 1NA      
--         112     202207      202208 1NA     
--         112     202208      202207 1NA
```

It is pretty much the same - just showing next period instead of previous.
***NOTE***: If rehire to a contract means the same contract then -
**OVER(Partition By EMP_ID, CONTRACT ....)**

To do the opposite (***non-consecutive periods***):

```sql
SELECT  EMP_ID, PERIOD "PERIOD", NEXT_PERIOD "NEXT_PERIOD", CONTRACT
FROM    (Select EMP_ID, PERIOD, CONTRACT, 
              LEAD(PERIOD, 1, 0) OVER(Partition By EMP_ID Order By PERIOD) "NEXT_PERIOD"
       From contracts)
WHERE   NEXT_PERIOD != 0 And CASE WHEN SubStr(NEXT_PERIOD, 1, 4) = SubStr(PERIOD, 1, 4) 
                                THEN NEXT_PERIOD - PERIOD
                           ELSE NEXT_PERIOD - (PERIOD + 88)  -- handling the year  change
                           END > 1
--  
--  R e s u l t :
--      EMP_ID     PERIOD NEXT_PERIOD CONTRACT
--  ---------- ---------- ----------- --------
--         111     202206      202209 1NA
```

Comment: I assumed that by "a rehire" OP meant that there is no previous period (and it's not the first period for that employee) but there are earlier records. In the sample data, emp id 111 is a rehire because he had a contract in period 202209 but not in 202208 and he had records for 202206 and prior.

Comment: @KoenLostrie As said - it is unclear without expcted result...

Answer (score 0):

From Oracle 12, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` to perform row-by-row pattern matching:

```sql
SELECT  emp_id, period, contract
FROM    contracts
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  PARTITION BY contract
  ORDER BY period
  MEASURES
    FIRST(emp_id) AS emp_id,
    LAST(period)  AS period
  AFTER MATCH SKIP TO FIRST different_emp
  PATTERN (emp+ different_emp+ emp)
  DEFINE
    emp           AS FIRST(emp_id) =  emp_id,
    different_emp AS FIRST(emp_id) != emp_id
);
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE contracts (EMP_ID, PERIOD, CONTRACT) as 
SELECT 111, 202204, '1NA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 111, 202205, '1NA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 111, 202206, '1NA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 112, 202207, '1NA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 112, 202208, '1NA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 111, 202209, '1NA' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| EMP_ID | PERIOD | CONTRACT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 202209 | 1NA |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/V6nGc-QL)